# Pesquisa em arquivo .txt

Tags: c, c++

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade que é pedido para fazer um sistema de cadastro de livros de uma biblioteca, toda a parte de cadastro já está pronta porém falta a parte de pesquisa que é onde não sei como fazer pois sou novato na área de linguagem C estou deixando meu código aqui para que possa dar uma olhada e quem sabe me ajudar a como fazer uma pesquisa em um arquivo .txt

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

```
void menu(){

    printf ("\n\n1 - Cadastrar\n");
    printf ("2 - Listar todos os livros.\n");
    printf ("3 - Listar todas as revistas.\n");
    printf ("4 - Listar as obras por caixa.\n");
    printf ("0 - Sair\n");
}

FILE* AbreArquivo(char modo, char caminho[100]){

    FILE *arquivo;
    switch(modo){

        case 'g':
            arquivo = fopen(caminho,"wt");
            break;
        case 'l':
            arquivo = fopen(caminho,"rt");
            break;
        case 'a':
            arquivo = fopen(caminho,"a");
            break;
    }

    if(arquivo==NULL){

        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo");
        exit(0);

    }

    return arquivo;
}

void FecharArquivo(FILE *arquivo){

    fclose(arquivo);

}

void Cadastra(char titulo[1000],char editora[1000], char autor[1000], int caixa, int ano, int ISBN){

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('a', "livros.txt");
    fprintf(arquivo, "%s  %s  %s  %d  %d  %d\n\n", titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);

    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
}

void CadastraRevista(char titulo[70],char editora[70], char autor[70], int caixa, int ano, int ISBN){

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('a', "revistas.txt");
    fprintf(arquivo, "%s %s %s %d %d %d\n\n", titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);
    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
}

void Listar(){
    FILE *arquivo;
    char titulo[1000];
    char autor[1000];
    char editora[1000];
    int caixa;
    int ano;
    int ISBN;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('l',"livros.txt");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tListando Livros....\n\n");
    while(!feof(arquivo)){
        fscanf(arquivo,"%1000[^\n] %1000[^\n] %1000[^\n] %d %d %d\n", &titulo, &autor, &editora, &caixa, &ano, &ISBN);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        for(int i=0; i<120; i++)printf ("*");
        printf("\nTitulo: %s\n  \nAutor: %s\n   \nEditora: %s\n   \nCaixa: %d\n   \nAno: %d\n   \nISBN: %d\n\n", titulo, editora, autor, caixa, ano, ISBN);
    }
    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
```

}

```
void ListarRevista(){
    FILE *arquivo;
    char titulo[1000];
    char autor[1000];
    char editora[1000];
    int caixa;
    int ano;
    int ISBN;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('l',"revistas.txt");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tListando Revistas....\n\n");
    while(!feof(arquivo)){
        fscanf(arquivo,"%70[^\n] %70[^\n] %70[^\n] %d %d %d\n", &titulo, &autor, &editora, &caixa, &ano, &ISBN);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        for(int i=0; i<120; i++)printf ("*");
        printf("\nTitulo: %s\n  \nAutor: %s\n   \nEditora: %s\n   \nCaixa: %d\n   \nAno: %d\n   \nISBN: %d\n\n", titulo,editora ,autor , caixa, ano, ISBN);
    }
    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
```

}

```
int main(){

    char titulo[1000];
    char autor[1000];
    char editora[1000];
    int caixa;
    int ano;
    int ISBN;
    int opcao;
    int opcao2;
    int voltar;

    topo:
    

    do{
        menu();
        printf("\nDigite uma opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        system("cls");
        if (opcao == 1 ){
            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tOBS:NAO USAR ACENTOS\n");
            printf("\nDigite 1 para livros ou 2 para revistas: ");
            scanf("%d", &opcao2);
            system("cls");
        }else{
            goto listagem;
        }
            Cad:
        switch(opcao2){
            case 1:

                printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tCadastrando Livros...\n\n");
                printf("\nDigite o titulo: ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(titulo, 1000, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o autor: ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(autor,1000, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o editora: ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(editora, 1000, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite a caixa: ");
                scanf("%d", &caixa);

                printf("\nDigite o ano: ");
                scanf("%d", &ano);

                printf("\nDigite o ISBN: ");
                scanf("%d", &ISBN);
                Cadastra(titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);
                printf("\n Digite 1 para continuar cadastrando e 2 para voltar ao menu: ");
                scanf("%d", &voltar);
                if(voltar==2){
                  system("cls");
                  goto topo;
                }else{
                    system("cls");
                    goto Cad;
                }
                system("cls");

                break;

            case 2:

                printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tCadastrando Revistas...\n\n");
                printf("\nDigite o titulo: ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(titulo, 100, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o autor: ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(autor,70, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o editora: ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(editora, 70, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite a caixa: ");
                scanf("%d", &caixa);

                printf("\nDigite o ano: ");
                scanf("%d", &ano);

                printf("\nDigite o ISBN: ");
                scanf("%d", &ISBN);
                CadastraRevista(titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);
                printf("\n Digite 1 para continuar cadastrando e 2 para voltar ao menu: ");
                scanf("%d", &voltar);
                if(voltar==2){
                  system("cls");
                  goto topo;
                }else{
                    system("cls");
                    goto Cad;
                }
                system("cls");
                break;
        }

    }while(opcao!=0);

    listagem:
    switch(opcao){
            case 2:
                Listar();
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                goto topo;
                break;

            case 3:
                ListarRevista();
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                goto topo;
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Opcao nao funcional!\n\n");
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                goto topo;

            case 0:
                printf("Finalizando......\n\n");
                system("pause");
                exit(0);

            default:
                printf("Erro ");
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                goto topo;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me recuso a analisar um programa que utiliza `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

Manipular Strings em C é um pouco mais complicado do que na maioria das linguagens.

Para fazer pesquisas em arquivos texto em C você deverá fazer um LOOP lendo todo o arquivo e checando caracter por caracter para encontrar a STRING que você está pesquisando.

Exemplo:

```
FILE *f = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");
char c;
int i;
char* string_pesquisar = "Revista Epoca";
while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
    if(c == *string_pesquisar){ //Primeiro caracter da STRING que estamos buscando foi encontrado, vamos checas os subsequentes:

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(string_pesquisar); i ++){ //loop para comparar cada caracter da String pesquisada com o proximo caracter lido
            c = fgetc(f); //lê mais um caracter no arquivo
            if(c == EOF)  //se encontrar o final do arquivo sai do loop
                break;
            if(*(string_pesquisar + i) != c) //se algum caracter subsequente lido for diferente da string pesquisada sai do loop
                break;
        }

        if(i == strlen(string_pesquisar){ //se i == qtd caracteres da String a pesquisar então achamos a string (a verificação não foi interrompida durante as comparações de caracteres)
             //Aqui entra o seu código ao achar a STRING que você procurava

             break; //break para parar de ler o arquivo
        }
     }
}

fclose(f);
```

Existe um HEADER para C com funções para manipulação de string, além do string.h, você pode encontrá-lo aqui:
https://gist.github.com/raphaelnapi/ed0c29e049ee6dd0d36d687b77b9ee0a

Com esse header no seu projeto você pode utilizar a função instr() para pesquisar uma string dentro de outra. Ele retornará a posição do primeiro caracter da String pesquisada ou -1 caso não a encontre.

Exemplo:

```
instr(0, "Código escrito em C", "escrito");
```

Essa chamada para função instr() buscará a string "escrito" dentro da string "Código escrito em C" a partir da posição 0 (primeiro caracter) e retornará um inteiro com valor 7 (posição da letra 'e' da string "escrito" na primeira string).

Note que você deverá diferenciar minusculas de maiusculas. Para isso é interessante fazer com que todos os caracteres da STRING a pesquisar e da STRING pesquisada sejam minusculas antes de realizar a pesquisa. Com esse HEADER é possível fazer isso com a função lower().

Answer (score 0):

Seu programa parece muito complicado sem necessidade. Escreva seu programa em torno dos dados. Sempre.

Em geral quando se pede esse tipo de solução para um aluno ele aprendeu já temas como estruturas, estruturas de dados e alocação de memória. Não sei se é o seu caso.

Vou te dar uns palpites apenas, afinal já passou muito tempo. Se precisar ainda de ajuda volte a escrever.

### De volta ao problema

Você tem um ou mais arquivos em disco com o acervo, porque parece que mantem revistas e livros em arquivos separados, e tem umas coisas que precisa fazer com o acervo, como listar todos por algum critério ou editar.

Em C você pode agrupar dados em uma estrutura, declarando assim

```
typedef struct
{
    char    titulo[40];
    char    editora[40];
    char    autor[40];
    int     caixa;
    int     ano;
    char    ISBN[20]; // 123-4-56-789ABC-D
    char    tipo; // 'L' para livro
}   Livro;
```

Um Livro. Note que pode usar tamanhos mais modestos para os campos. 1.000 letras é um pouco exagerado para autor, título ou editora como você havia usado. E `int` para ISBN, um formato estabelecido no mundo todo, é errado.

E o `acervo` é uma coleção de `Livro`. Não há razão para usar dois arquivos a menos que o enunciado exija. E um acervo pode ser algo mínimo como

```
typedef struct
{
    int     total;
    Livro   livro[200]
}   Acervo;
```

E uma biblioteca poderia ser algo assim

```
Acervo    loja1;
loja1.total = 0;
```

Para começar a ler do disco o acervo da loja 1.

Em geral se usaria alocação dinâmica de memória para esses campos todos. E muitas vezes uma lista ligada ou outra estrutura de dados para os livros. Mas pode ser mesmo um simples vetor.

### E os arquivos?

Em geral na entrada os dados do arquivo são todos lidos para um vetor de estruturas na memória. Todo o processamento é feito nessa estrutura. Ao final do programa a estrutura é copiada de volta para o disco com outro nome. Aí se muda o nome do arquivo original para uma extensão de backup e se muda o arquivo novo para o nome original. Assim se você começou com *"livros.txt"* vai acabar com *"livros.txt"* e *"livros.bak"*. Nada original.

Muitas vezes cada edição é salva em disco em um arquivo, quando o conteúdo é importante. Algo como um arquivo de transações, um *log*. Assim se o programa cancelar depois de horas de edição você pode entrar com um programa que abre o arquivo original e esse *log* de transações e atualiza tudo antes de voltar a rodar.

Não se edita direto no arquivo porque é problemático no mínimo. É possível e simples, são poucas funções para posicionar o arquivo, encontrar um registro, regravar um trecho e tal. Apenas não vale o esforço a menos que o enunciado exija usar isso. Funções simples como `rewind()` `fseek()` `fopen()`, `fclose()` e família.